# When I try to compile, I keep getting this error class is not abstract and does not override abstract method update(Object) in MyObserver

Tags: observable, observer-pattern, observers

PokemonTrainer is not abstract and does not override abstract method update(Object) in MyObserver
public class PokemonTrainer implements MyObserver {
       ^
method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override

```
public class PokemonTrainer implements MyObserver {

    private String myName; /** @invariant myName != "" */

    /**
        @param name The name of the PokemonTrainer
        @since Sunday, Sep 9, 2018

        @custom.require name != ""
    */
    public PokemonTrainer(String name) {
        myName = name;
    }

    /**
        @return A string corresponding to the PokemonTrainer's name
        @custom.ensure  getName() != ""
    */
    public String getName() {
        return myName;

    } 

    @Override
    public void update(MyObservable obs, Object o) {
        String whatHappened = "";
        whatHappened += this + " is notified that " + o;
        System.out.println(whatHappened);
    }

    /**
        @return Returns a string corresponding the the state of the PokemonTrainer
    */
    public String toString() {
        String returnval = "";
        returnval += "PokemonTrainer " + myName;
        return returnval;
    }

} // end class PokemonTrainer
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because update() methods of MyObserver and PokemonTrainer have different signatures (different arguments): 
update(Object o) in MyObserver
update(MyObservable obs, Object o) in PokemonTrainer